# Get All Indexes Of array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here Is MY Output OF problem i want to get all reciver_id indexes from this array and after getting all indexes i want to get the result from another table users against these id's

```
$data['cat_row']        =       $this->messages_model->get_sentnotify($user_id);
        foreach($data['cat_row'] as $key){
            $profile    =   $key['reciver_id'];
        }
 $data['profile']        =       $this->messages_model->Sender_profile($profile);
```

through this code i get only 1 value of first index how to get all...
getting all i want to get users from other table against each id

```
function Sender_profile($profile)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $profile);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db_table2);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

kindly help me about sql also how i get all values from database in one iteration
[image]

Comment: You mean that you need to access each index inside of the result array, right?

Comment: i want to show name against each reciever id at one page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code **Part 1**

Get all **reciver_id** in an array like follows:

```
$data['cat_row'] = $this->messages_model->get_sentnotify($user_id);

$profile = [];

foreach($data['cat_row'] as $key){

  array_push($profile, $key['reciver_id']);

}

$data['profile'] = $this->messages_model->Sender_profile($profile);
```

Code **Part 2**

Use Codeigniter's **where_in()** function.

```
function Sender_profile($profile) {

  $this->db->where_in('id', $profile);

  $query = $this->db->get($this->db_table2);

  return $query->result_array();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller , you need to access all your receiver_id then modify your foreach loop:

```
$i=0;
foreach($data['cat_row'] as $key){
        $profile[$i]    =   $key['reciver_id'];
        $i++;
    }
```

Now you have all your receiver_id in $profile array.  and pass this array in controller function and should query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6);// Just for example you need to modify your query according to your need.
```